# Query batch job metadata in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-data-jpa

I want to fetch the 10 latest records from the BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION-table joined with the BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE-table.

So how can I access these tables?

In this application I have used Spring Data JPA. It's another application which uses Spring Batch and created these tables. In other words, I would just like to run a JOIN-query and map it directly to my custom object with just the necessary fields. As far as it's possible, I would like to avoid making seperate models for the two tables. But I don't know the best approach here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it from Spring Batch code you need to use [JobExplorer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) and apply filters on either `START_TIME` or `END_TIME`. Alternatively, just send an `SQL` query with your desired `JOIN` to the DB using JDBC. The `DDLs` of the metadata tables can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html).

**EDIT**

If you want to try to do it in SpringBatch, I guess you need to iterate through `JobExecutions` and find the ones that interest you, then do your thing )) someth. like:

```
List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName);

for (JobInstance jobInstance : jobInstances) {
    List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance);
    for (JobExecution jobExecution : jobExecutions) {
        if (//jobExecution.getWhatever...)) {
        // do your thing...
        }
     }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Had a look at JobExplorer, but I didn't find an appropriate method of doing that query. However, JDBC might be the easiest approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since `JobExplorer` doesn't have the interface `.getJobInstances(jobName)` anymore, I have done this (this example with `BatchStatus` as a condition) adapted with streams :

```
List<JobInstance> lastExecutedJobs = jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobName, 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);

Optional<JobExecution> jobExecution = lastExecutedJobs
                                .stream()
                                .map(jobExplorer()::getJobExecutions)
                                .flatMap(jes -> jes.stream())
                                .filter(je -> BatchStatus.COMPLETED.equals(je.getStatus()))
                                .findFirst();
```

To return N elements, you could use others capacities of stream (limit, max, collectors, ...).